# How to get the setup menu on a HP Pavilion 550-170na Desktop PC

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10, setup, hp-pavilion

This is a new PC and it works ok with the default install of Windows 10 Home edition on a slow disk, but I want to wipe that out and install Win 10 Pro on an SSD instead.

But I can't find a way to get to the setup menus or a boot menu before windows boots. The only way I can get screen output (its hdmi) is to let it boot up to the default drive, then windows appears onscreen as expected.

I think whats happening is that there is no video support until windows is running. Because if I do frantically press f10, esc and f1 then windows never appears, whereas if I leave it boot it eventually does appear. So I can't find any way of getting to a boot menu.

I've also tried f2 which brings up setup on my dell computers, no luck.

All ideas welcome - thank you

Comment: The "HP User Guide - Windows 10" for the HP Pavilion 550-170na, which you can find at [User Guides](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Pavilion-550-100-Desktop-PC-series/8499648/model/9240346/manuals), references pressing esc "To start HP PC Hardware Diagnostics UEFI", but also suggests you "press or tap f2", so you've tried the keys that should have worked. All of [the HP systems I've worked with](http://support.moonpoint.com/hardware/pc/bios/) have used either F10 or F2 to access a setup menu and, except for an HP M/N: DV6 laptop which used F9, have used ESC to access a boot menu.

Comment: Hold the shift key down when selecting shutdown from the start menu,   F10 (system setup) should work on the next boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your OEM PC does not provide a quick and clean way for you to get into UEFI settings/boot menu (when Windows is found), you can go to the following after boot:

[image]

(Start -> Settings -> Update & Security -> Recovery -> Advanced Startup -> Restart Now)

Then click "Use a device" to see if your Windows Installation CD/USB is found. If not, you may need to go deeper to get into the UEFI settings and see if there are options that should be adjusted:

Troubleshoot (instead of "Use a device) -> Advanced Options -> UEFI firmware settings

Comment: Yes, after a zillion reboots its finally working. The monitor keeps resetting itself away from the HDMI port. I eventually discovered that I have to press buttons on the monitor after every reboot to get a screen. So I now have access to F10. Still this is a good answer as the method you showed will stop windows doing a fast boot where the cd etc is ignored.. thank you